# Prove that $6n+n^7$ is divisible by $7$ for $n>0$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction, divisibility

> Prove that $6n+n^7$ is divisible by $7$ for $n>0$.

Skip the $n=1$ part...

Induction hypothesis:
$P(k)=6k+k^7=k(6+k^6)$ is divisible by $7$

For $n=k+1$, we have that $$P(k+1)=6(k+1)+(k+1)^7=(k+1)[6+(k+1)^6]$$
How should I continue? Thanks

Comment: Here's a thing (for this problem and others): if you have an epression in $n$, and you decide for whatever reason (make it induction) to substitute "$n$" with "$k+1$", then you must do some manipulation that uses the fact that you've written "$k+1$" instead "$n$". If you could solve it with manipulation that you can do with the expression in "$n$" (say, grouping a "$k+1$" instead of grouping a "$n$"), then you *would* have solved it already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(k+1)^7=\binom{7}{0}+\binom{7}{1}k^1+\binom{7}{2}k^2+\cdots+\binom{7}{6}k^6+\binom{7}{7}k^7$$

$$(k+1)^7=1+7k+\binom{7}{2}k^2+\cdots+\binom{7}{6}k^6+k^7$$
$$P(k+1)=6(k+1)+(k+1)^7=6k+6+1+k^7+7(...)$$
$$P(k+1)=6(k+1)+(k+1)^7=6k+7+k^7+7(...)$$
$$P(k+1)=6(k+1)+(k+1)^7=(6k+k^7)+7+7(...)$$

$6k+k^7$ is already divisible by 7 as you assumed this, other remaining terms  are also multiple of 7 thus divisible by 7

$$ \forall  n\ge 1 \hspace{10pt}  P(n) \implies P(n+1)$$

Comment: Where did the 1 come from and how do we know the remaining terms are multiple of 7? I am kinda new :/

Comment: can you see it now updated the answer

Comment: Yeah, it's pretty clear now. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative by FLT we have that

$$6n+n^7 \equiv-n+n\equiv 0 \pmod 7$$

Comment: (+1) nice. Did you get the invite btw?

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Thanks! Yes I saw that but I didn't undestand what it was aimed to.

Comment: Are you interested in the idea of math challenges on SE?

Answer (score 2):

Since $\binom7i$ is divisible by $7$ for $i\ne0,7$, we have that \begin{align}P(k+1)&=\color{red}{6(k+1)}+\color{blue}{(k+1)^7}\\&=\color{red}{6k+6}+\color{blue}{k^7+7(\text{something})+1}\\&=(6k+k^7)+7(\text{something}+1)\end{align} which is divisible by $7$ from the induction hypothesis.

Answer (score 1):

Write
$$(n^7-n)+7n=\frac{(n-1)n(n+1)\left((2n-1)^2+3\right)\left((2n+1)^2+3\right)}{16}+7n$$

If $7\mid n$ we are done, if $7\not\mid n$ there are some possibilities:

- $n=7k+1\Rightarrow 7\mid n-1$
- $n=7k+2\Rightarrow 7\mid (2n+1)^2+3$
- $n=7k+3\Rightarrow 7\mid (2n-1)^2+3$
- $n=7k-3\Rightarrow 7\mid (2n+1)^2+3$
- $n=7k-2\Rightarrow 7\mid (2n-1)^3+3$
- $n=7k-1\Rightarrow 7\mid n+1$

We don't have to worry about $16=2^4$ in the denominator, since $\gcd(2,7)=1$, and both:

- $4\mid (2n-1)^2+3$
- $4\mid (2n+1)^2+3$

are true.

Answer (score 1):

There are, in my opinion, two possible approaches.

The first one is to show it is true for $n=1, \ldots , 7$ and then show by induction that if it's true for $n$ then it's true for $n+7$.

The second one is to use the [Fermat's Little Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem)

Answer (score 1):

Alt. hint:  the product of $7$ consecutive numbers is always divisible by $7$, so:

$$
\begin{align}
7\;\mid\; (n-3)(n-2)(n-1)n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3) &= n^7 - 14 n^5 + 49 n^3 - 36 n \\
 &= n^7+6n -\left(14n^5-49n^3+42n\right) \\
 &= n^7+6n - 7\left(2n^5-7n^3+6n\right)
\end{align}
$$